# Where is the retribution buff coming from?

Tags: hearthstone

I just played the brawl and got Tyrion. I played him, and he was 7/6 for no apparent reason.

He had a buff called retribution coming from [this](http://hearthstone.buffed.de/en/card/Retribution-2404), but I have no idea what invoked it. What gave him that buff?

Comment: Was it a Shifter Zerus that had previously been a Bolvar Fordragon?

Comment: @dpatchery: yep

Comment: @dpatchery: does that passive affect not revoke from the shifter?:O

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The [Retribution buff](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Goblins_vs_Gnomes_enchantment_list) comes from Bolvar Fordragon.

In your comment you affirmed that the Tyrion being played was actually a Shifter Zerus. The retribution effect must have been triggered on a previous turn when the Shifter was transformed into Bolvar Fordragon and you played a minion from your hand.

This behavior is documented in Shifter Zerus's [gamepedia entry](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Shifter_Zerus):

> Buffs from cards like The Mistcaller, Grimestreet Outfitter,
> Smuggler's Run, and any other card that provides attached enchantments
> to Zerus will **not be removed** by Zerus' transformation
> effect. This also includes cost reduction from Emperor
> Thaurissan and Unstable Portal. Additionally, if he is temporarily
> C'Thun or **Bolvar Fordragon**, he can gain relevant buffs and **keep them
> even after transforming further**